# Compiling Boost 1.54 XCode5 for device - fatal error: error in backend: symbol '___umodsi3' can not be undefined in a subtraction expression

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, boost, xcode5

I have been able to successfully compile boost 1.54 for the iOS 7.0 simulator using XCode 5, but when trying to compile for device getting this strange clang failure:

darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/darwin-7.0~iphone/release/architecture-arm/link-static/macosx-version-iphone-7.0/target-os-iphone/threading-multi/lockpool.o
**fatal error: error in backend: symbol '___umodsi3' can not be undefined in a subtraction expression**
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: arm-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix

Here are my user-config.jam settings:

```
using clang : : : <cxxflags>"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" <linkflags>"-stdlib=libc++" ;

using darwin : 7.0~iphone
   : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
   : <striper> <root>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
     <compileflags>"-arch armv7"
     <compileflags>"-arch armv7s"
     <compileflags>-mthumb
     <compileflags>-fvisibility=hidden
     <compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
     <compileflags>-std=c++11
     <compileflags>-stdlib=libc++
     <compileflags>-miphoneos-version-min=5.1
     <compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
     <compileflags>"-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk"
   : <architecture>arm <target-os>iphone
   ;

using darwin : 7.0~iphonesim
   : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
   : <striper> <root>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
     <compileflags>"-arch i386"
     <compileflags>-fvisibility=hidden
     <compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
     <compileflags>-std=c++11
     <compileflags>-stdlib=libc++
     <compileflags>-miphoneos-version-min=5.1
     <compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
     <compileflags>"-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk"
   : <architecture>x86 <target-os>iphone
   ;
```

Detailed steps to reproduce:

```
1. Download and extract the latest sources for boost 1.54
2. Create a user-config.jam in user's home directory (w text above).
3. Run ./bootstrap.sh in the boost directory
4. Run
```

```
./b2  toolset=darwin-7.0~iphone architecture=arm target-os=iphone macosx-version=iphone-7.0 threading=multi linkflags=-stdlib=libc++ define=_LITTLE_ENDIAN link=static install
```

This will result in the error above.

For comparison, when compiling for the simulator with the following line:

```
./b2 toolset=darwin-7.0~iphonesim architecture=x86 target-os=iphone macosx-version=iphone-7.0 threading=multi linkflags=-stdlib=libc++ link=static install
```

This works fine and correctly generates the boost libraries for use with the simulator.

Would anyone have a suggestion as to what could be causing this? Is it a clang compiler problem or am I using the device compile incorrectly? I have been able to compile for device with XCode 4.x with no problem previously...

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: id you make progress on this? I ran into the same error and can't find any solution yet. There are just a few sources where this is mentioned again like llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10992 or https://www.mail-archive.com/cfe-users@cs.uiuc.edu/msg00402.html or http://answer.techwikihow.com/830119/compiling-boost-1-54-xcode5-device-fatal-error-error-backend-symbol-___umodsi3-undefined-subtraction.html

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the answer. Use

```
<compileflags>-mno-thumb
```

instead of:

```
<compileflags>-mthumb
```

Works for me now.